# How to process a file uploaded from the Web for usage in a Bash Script?

Tags: bash

I have a Bash script from the terminal that accepts a file as one of its arguments.

I want a user from the web to upload a file within the UI. Then that file would be used as one of the arguments in the Bash script. I am assuming the file and Bash Script will have to be in a server. Then, I want to print the results of the Bash script to the user in their UI.

What technologies and architecture would you use to achieve this? I do not want to recreate the Bash script.

Comment: This is a huge topic. Assuming that you are using Linux, I suggest that you start by installing Apache, and studying CGI scripting. However, there are much more modern Web development frameworks available for many scripting languages other than bash (e.g. Perl, Python, PHP, and Java, to name a few).

Comment: Huge indeed.  I would do it in PHP.  On upload of the file, save it on disk and call the script on it.  Beware, this can be quite dangerous since the content of the uploaded file could be used to execute commands, hack the site, ...

Comment: Apache or Nginx are good starts. Make sure you configure Apache/Nginx with a reasonable max POST size and timeout, as well as virus scanning any uploaded files (e.g. with ClamAV or similar). Also, be very careful about storing these files and/or allowing them to be downloaded after upload, as this could allow anyone with access to the page to use you as a virtual hard drive, and could lead to very bad things being stored on your server.